# Why This Query is returning only 1 Row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Kindly see the Table Structure , Query and the Result.

MeetingRoom

```
   ID | Area | RoomNo    Capacity   distances 
   --- ----- --------- ---------- ----------
   1   1     R1         10        10        
   2   1     R3         24        4         
   3   8     R4         24        4         
   4   1     R5         10        10
```

ReservationTable

```
ReservationID RoomID      DateTimeStart           DateTimeEnd             
------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- 
1             1           2013-10-10 17:00:00.000 2013-10-10 19:00:00.000
```

Query

```
 Declare @Start Datetime
 Declare @End Datetime

 set @Start='2013-10-10 13:00:00.000'
 set @End='2013-10-10 14:00:00.000'

 select 
     MeetingRoom.ID 
 from 
    MeetingRoom 
    left Join ResReservationTable Res on Res.RoomID = MeetingRoom.ID
 Where 
   Res.DateTimeStart != @Start and Res.DateTimeEnd != @End
   and (Res.DateTimeStart Not Between @Start and @End) 
   and (Res.DateTimeEnd Not Between @Start and @End)
```

This Query is Returning only one record as it should return 4 Records

Comment: What is Res? What is the data within it? So why don't you show us the data in it? How many rows and what RoomID values does it contain?

Comment: @PreetSangha Res is table name , contains Reservation Details for Meeting Rooms

Comment: How you thinking that will return four records. From your joining it's clear that only one row is matching with your condition. If ReservationTable RoomID was used more time in MeetingRoom then you can aspect to get more result....

Comment: Because I am using left join so it should bring 3 records that are not in the Reservation table and 1 more record because the conditions are true for this record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  and in `WHERE clause` set condition to right-hand table rather than `IS NULL` in result you have `INNER JOIN`.

I think this is what you want.

```
Declare @Start Datetime
Declare @End Datetime

set @Start='2013-10-10 13:00:00.000'
set @End='2013-10-10 14:00:00.000'

select 
     MeetingRoom.ID 
from 
    MeetingRoom 
    left Join ResReservationTable Res on Res.RoomID = MeetingRoom.ID
Where
  (
   Res.DateTimeStart != @Start and Res.DateTimeEnd != @End
   and (Res.DateTimeStart Not Between @Start and @End) 
   and (Res.DateTimeEnd Not Between @Start and @End)
  )
  OR Res.ReservationID IS NULL
```

I think you must rephrase your `WHERE` condition. If you want room which fully free (i.e. intervals not intersect) you can use this:

```
WHERE
   Res.DateTimeStart > @End
   OR Res.DateTimeEnd < @Start
   OR Res.ReservationID IS NULL
```

Comment: in this query if I am giving values like

set @Start='2013-10-10 17:00:00.000'
set @End='2013-10-10 19:00:00.000'

then it is returning 4 rows as it should return 3

Comment: I marked your answer correct as it was working fine. But now I am having a problem. If there are multiple records for a room in ResReservationTable problem, then this query is returning that room also which is reserved at the  given date time, because the conditions are getting true for that room.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an inner join...
**edit** 
You must use outer join as you are doing but consider how null values compare with non null values...

One way is to explicitly accept null date values with an OR clause

Comment: even using inner join its returning the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to move the stuff from the WHERE clause up into the ON clause:

```
select 
    MeetingRoom.ID 
from MeetingRoom 
left Join ResReservationTable Res on Res.RoomID = MeetingRoom.ID
and Res.DateTimeStart != @Start and Res.DateTimeEnd != @End
and Res.DateTimeStart Not Between @Start and @End
and Res.DateTimeEnd Not Between @Start and @End
```

And hey presto, you keep the outer join but still filter the results, plus you now have the best performing version of the query.

It is a very common, and incorrect, assumption that join conditions may only have "key related" expressions, but in fact you can have any condition, even ones on columns not involved in the tables being joined.

Comment: in this query if I am giving values like set @Start='2013-10-10 17:00:00.000' set @End='2013-10-10 19:00:00.000' then it is returning 4 rows as it should return 3

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this? It uses "Outer" and checks for NULL values which are returned for rooms that have no reservation and returns those rows too.

```
Declare @Start Datetime
 Declare @End Datetime

 set @Start='2013-10-10 13:00:00.000'
 set @End='2013-10-10 14:00:00.000'

 select 
     MeetingRoom.ID 
 from 
    MeetingRoom 
    left Outer Join ResReservationTable Res on Res.RoomID = MeetingRoom.ID
 Where 
   (Res.DateTimeStart is NULL OR Res.DateTimeEnd is NULL)
   and Res.DateTimeStart != @Start and Res.DateTimeEnd != @End
   and (Res.DateTimeStart Not Between @Start and @End) 
   and (Res.DateTimeEnd Not Between @Start and @End)
```

Comment: its not even bringing 1 record, should bring 4